# how to navigate from one page to another without refreshing the result in java

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a **search page** where you give some inputs and click on a "**search**" button after which you get a list of result on the same page in the form of table. when you select one record from the table you get navigated to another page which is **details page**(which has a "cancel" button) which has all the details about that record,it also has a **cancel** button.

once i press the **cancel** button it goes to the first page i.e. the search page but the search result is not there(the table which got generated earlier when i pressed "search" button).

It gets cleared off. I want that table to be there when i come back to the search page after pressing cancel.

I am using richfaces and JSF.

Comment: This has essentially nothing to do with Java and is all about HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: okay. i thought we can store the search result in some session variable and then use it. but i wasn't sure

Comment: Where are you storing the search results? In a RequestScoped bean?

Comment: It is stored inside the search bean in the form of list

Comment: Just pass current page as request parameter. How exactly to do that depends on the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is unfortunately missing in your question.

Comment: once the SEARCH button is pressed its action is searchSubmit() method inside the search bean. This method takes care of populating the search result

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can return the page name from you Action method.
To avoid tight coupling or low cohesion you can return a result string from your Action method and in `faces-config.xml` define the page for particular result.
For Example:

```
public String mySubmit(){
   String returnString = null;
   if(operationSuccess){
       returnString = "SUBMIT_SUCCESS";
   }else{
       returnString = "SUBMIT_FAIL";
   }
}
```

In faces-config.xml define the navigaion

```
<navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>SUBMIT_SUCCESS</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>
   <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>SUBMIT_FAIL</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/error.xhtml</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```